# How to filter list using custom filter and checkboxes in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular7

I have a list of data in `cardData` list and I'm looping over it using `ngFor` to display a card for each item. I want to filter the cards by card-name which is captured in the `filterName` property.

I also have a custom filter: I'm using checkboxes to select the `filterName`. When I select one single checkbox it's working fine but I want to be able to select multiple checkboxes and filter accordingly. I would appreciate some help.

```html
<div class="card-list cursor-move" cdkDrag *ngFor="let cardDet of cardData | filter:filterName">
<input type="checkbox" value="{{filterDet.title}}" (change)="filterValue($event.target.value,$event.target.checked)">
```

```
enter code here

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter',
  pure: false
})
@Injectable()
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

   /* @param items List of items to filter
    @param term a string term to compare with every property of the list*/

  static filter(items: Array<{ [key: string]: any }>, term: string): Array<{ [key: string]: any }> {

    const toCompare = term.toLowerCase();


    return items.filter(function (item: any) {
      for (const property in item) {
        if (item[property] === null) {
          continue;
        }
        if (item[property].toString().toLowerCase().includes(toCompare)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    });
  }

  transform(items: any, term: string): any {
    if (!term || !items) {
      return items;
    }
    return FilterPipe.filter(items, term);
  }
}
  //filterValue() is called onChange on the checkbox

  filterValue(value,checked){
    console.log(checked);
    if(checked){
      console.log(value);
      this.filterName = value;
    }
    else{
         this.filterName='';
    }

  }
```

Comment: This is a little hard for me to understand without seeing what is being passed as `term`. It's a string value, but you want to be able to select multiple checkboxes - should you instead be passing an Array of strings? Or, when multiple are selected, are you sending a comma-separated string of terms?

Comment: ok ,as of now filterName is a property which is just a string as my custom filter expects only one searchText which is "term".Now filterName property is being captured from checkbox.

Comment: I've included filterValue( ) function in the code for reference. As of now its just working for individual checkboxes and I intend it to be a filter on Array of checked values. say cardData | filter :filterName should be cardData | filter:filterData where filterData is an array of checked values

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, there are two things you need to do here. First, you need to capture multiple values from your checkboxes. Right now you are just overwriting a string with the latest checked checkbox:

```
filterValue(value,checked) {
   if(checked) {
     this.filterName = value;
   }
   else {
     this.filterName='';
   }
 }
```

One way you can do this if you are not looking to use any of Angular's existing forms/patterns (which I highly recommend you learn if you're unfamiliar, here are some sources to check out: [1](https://netbasal.com/handling-multiple-checkboxes-in-angular-forms-57eb8e846d21), [2](https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular), [3](https://medium.com/@DheerajJaiswal6/multi-checkbox-form-control-angular7-39cbdabede57)) is to make an `Array`. Let's pretend you made one and it's called `filterNameArray`. Now, you should rewrite your method to match the contents of `filterNameArray` to the checkboxes that are checked:

```
 filterValue(value,checked) {
   if(checked) { //add to array
     this.filterNameArray.push(value);
   }
   else { //remove from array
     this.filterNameArray = this.filterNameArray.filter(x => x != value);
   }
 }
```

As  you can see, we are adding a value to the `Array` when it is checked and removing it when it is not checked. To remove it we are filtering the `Array`. I've used an arrow function above because it is shorter and easier to read for some people, but if you are not familiar with arrow functions, it is equivalent to this wordier version:

```
function(x, value) {
    if (x == value) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When we use it with the `filter` `Array` function we are telling our code to run that function on every item in the `Array` (each item is represented by `x` in my rewritten method above) and return an `Array` containing only the values that made it return `true`. Hopefully that makes sense, but please feel free to ask me questions. Moving on!

Now we can assume that we have an `Array` that contains all the terms to filter the cards on (but remember you still need to pass this properly!). The next step is filter on this `Array` instead of a `string`.

```
return items.filter(function (item: any) {
  for (const property in item) {
    let cardName = item[property].toString().toLowerCase();
    if (item[property] === null) {
      continue;
    }
    if (toCompare.includes(cardName)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

I moved the string manipulation above the if-statements and stored it in a `let` just so what I did was easier to read. With this change, the card filter is looking through an `Array` and keeps a card if its name is found.

Comment: In my code there is something like this

static filter(items: Array<{ [key: string]: any }>, term: string).so 1. should I change term :string to term:string[ ]

Comment: 2. toCompare refers to this line in the code const toCompare = term.toLowerCase();
its throwing an error: term.LowerCase is not a function.

Comment: Yes, you should change the term parameter from `string` to `string[]`, and yes that `toLowerCase()` will throw an error since `term` is now an array. You can choose how you want to handle that, but one way is to make `toCompare` store the `term` array where each member has been mapped `toLowerCase()`: `const toCompare = term.map(x => x.toLowerCase());`